# S22.Imap fetch attachments

Tags: c#, email, attachment

I'm using S22.imap library to download all the emails from the mailbox. Some of the messages have attachments. I would like to forward some emails with the attachments or create a new email with the attachments from the mail form the mailbox.

The problem is, I can't fetch the attachments so I can add them as a new attachments to my message.

So basically:
I have a MailMessage object and I want to fetch the file that is attached to it and add it to new MailMessage object.

Comment: [C# stop being lazy and Start Coding your own stuff .Com](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
{
    byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.ContentStream.Length];
    int bytesRead = attachment.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.ContentStream.Length);
    string destinationFile = @"C:\\Path\\" + attachment.Name;
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
    writer.Write(allBytes);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have the same problem: I itarate through MailMessage objects:
foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments) and stream attachment.ContentStream. Then add streams to new message.